# VBA Excel, Returning a Variable between Forms

Tags: excel, forms, vba, variables

I need some help. I am writing VBA script for an Excel macro. I have two forms, the first has a button calling the second. On the second I want it to return a variable (`tempdate`, this is declared as `public type Date` in the main Worksheet).

Main form button code:

```
Private Sub SetDueButton_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
    DueDate.Value = tempdate 'display tempdate in the DueDate text box
End Sub
```

UserForm1 'ok' button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton53_Click()
     tempdate = TextBox1.Value
     Unload Me 
End Sub
```

What am I missing to get this variable to load whatever is in `TextBox1.Value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variable in a module, not the worksheet, and the declaration needs to be:

```
Global tempDate as Date
```

or

```
Public tempDate as Date
```

The variables in the worksheet are not available in the forms.

It would be possible to make a function in the worksheet and call this function, but this is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a property in the userform

Your main form code would change to look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub SetDueButton_Click()
    Dim UF As UserForm1 'you can declare a user form as an independent object

    UF.Show
    DueDate.Value = UF.tempdate 'get the property 
    Unload UF 'now you can unload or set to Nothing
End Sub
```

Your UserForm1 code would be this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get tempdate() As String
    tempdate = Me.TextBox1.Value 'Me refers to the form itself
End Property

Private Sub CommandButton53_Click()
     Me.Hide 'hide don't unload yet or you can't get the data.
End Sub
```

Comment: This is actually a better solution than I provided; I was just offering the easiest fix.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I used the public property method and it works great!